I can see in vb.net the header but when i print i disapper the header. Below is the code
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim format As New StringFormat
    format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    e.Graphics.DrawString("PULL OUT", New Font("Century Gothic", 25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, New Point(400, 20), format)

    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    Dim y As Integer = 100
    Dim x As Integer = 150
    Dim h As Integer = 0
    Dim rc As Rectangle
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow

    If newPage Then
        row = DataGridView1.Rows(mRow)
        x = 100
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rc)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, DataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If
        Next
        y += h
    End If

    newPage = False
    Dim displayNow As Integer
    For displayNow = mRow To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        row = DataGridView1.Rows(displayNow)
        x = 100
        h = 0

        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                rc.Offset(10, 0)
                'e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, DataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                'e.Graphics.DrawString("PULL OUT", New Font("Century Gothic", 25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, New Point(400, 20), format)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString, DataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If
        Next
        y += h
    Next
End Sub

In the vb.net the header is appering but when print it dissapper

Are you resetting newPage when you start printing? How you handle newPage seems important here, but you have not shown us the relevant code for it.

no sir . just creating table for data from datagridview. can you correct it sir

No, I cannot correct it as I don't see the relevant code. The part in If newPage Then will only be executed if newPage is true. You set it newPage = False afterwards, but I don't see any code setting it newPage = True. This must be done somewhere. Probably in the code that initiates printing (that you have not shown). Also PrintDocument1_PrintPage will be called for every page. So, why do you need this Boolean variable?

I'm betting that you haven't actually debugged this code, so you need to do that. You should have done it before you posted here and told us what you found. Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and then step through it line by line to see where and how it's behaviour doesn't match your expectations.
